# sf and rgdal are not working on Mac OS Big Sur, how to fix? --Closed

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal

```
 library(sf)
```

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/sf/libs/sf.so
Reason: image not found

```
 library(rgdal)
```

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgdal’ in get(method, envir = home):
lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rgdal/R/rgdal.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

----Issue closed----

CRAN libraries have been updated to be compatible with Big Sur which removed some system libraries, so just re-install rgdal and sf from CRAN (thanks to Jeroen). To make sure you get the latest versions use

```
install.packages(c("rgdal","sf"), "https://mac.R-project.org")
```

ref: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2020-November/013783.html

Comment: You'll probably have to wait a bit. The dependency chain is quite long and will have to be rebuilt

Comment: Oh, no..., many projects with geospatial works.

Comment: Hi! I've never used Mac OS so I cannot test this but you may want to check [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1536)

Comment: I think you should post your update as an *answer* rather than as an edit to the question.  The question is still valid ...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the R packages rely on the PostgreSQL library that Apple has removed from macOS 11. You can "fix" it for the time being by installing all the required components manually (`brew install gdal` should do it assuming you use Homebrew) and then re-installing the R packages from source. It's messy, since it will download multiple MBs of unnecessary development packages to your Mac, but it works. I hope that the package maintainers will soon include the missing libraries into the distribution of `sf` and `rgdal` directly.

Answer (score 4):

CRAN libraries have been updated to be compatible with Big Sur which removed some system libraries, so just re-install rgdal and sf from CRAN (thanks to Jeroen). To make sure you get the latest versions use

```
install.packages(c("rgdal","sf"), "https://mac.R-project.org")
```

ref: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2020-November/013783.html